# Maximum number of child process in Unix

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I have a question going in my mind. I just want to know what is the maximum limit on the number of child process when it is created by a process by using fork() system call?
I am using UBUNTU OS (12.04) with kernel 3.2.0-45-generic.

Comment: `ulimit -u` will tell you the max number of processes for a user.

Comment: But is it the the same as the maximum number of child process a process can create. As a user , I can run multiple process at the same time in the background  without creating any child process.

Comment: It is the same limit regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main()
{
    struct rlimit rl;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &rl);
    printf("%d\n", rl.rlim_cur);
}
```

where struct rlimit is:

```
struct rlimit {
    rlim_t rlim_cur;  /* Soft limit */
    rlim_t rlim_max;  /* Hard limit (ceiling for rlim_cur) */
};
```

From [man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit):

> **RLIMIT_NPROC**
>
> The maximum number of processes (or, more precisely on Linux, threads) that can be created for the real  user  ID  of the calling process.  Upon encountering this limit, fork(2) fails with the error EAGAIN.

Answer (score 2):

if you need the max process number of user limit , this code also work:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
void main()
{
        printf("MAX CHILD ID IS :%ld\n",sysconf(_SC_CHILD_MAX));
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `void main()` unless you're on Windows, where you probably can't use `sysconf()`.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336).  Also, the standards use `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>` and you should too.

Answer (score 0):

The number of process is not a by process limit, but a by user limit.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use:

```
ulimit -u
```

to tell you the max processes a user can run and using `-a` argument will tell you all the user limits.

Answer (score 0):

Answers are already there to get current maximum value.I would like to add that you can set this limit by making change in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

`sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf`

Then add this line to the bottom of that file

`hard     nproc     1000`

You can raise this to whatever number you want -

`nproc` is maximum number of processes that can exist simultaneously on the machine.